# Query between two tables

Tags: mysql, .net, database, executereader

This is my query with 2 parameters. Can someone please help me?

```
sql = "select * 
       from studentlist 
       where firstname like '%" 
     & Transaction.SEARCHSTUDENT.Text 
     & "%' or studentnum like '%" 
     & Transaction.SEARCHSTUDENT.Text 
     & "%' and not in (select studentnum from borrowing of books where status ='borrowed')"
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the problem or error you are facing? What help do you need?

Comment: Querry error. Im hoping to get the names from studentlist(table) that is not not in the table borrowing of books .

Comment: Creating queries by concatenating strings is just begging for bugs like this and SQL injection attacks. Instead of concatenating, use parameterized queries with eg a @name parameter (`WHERE FirstName LIKE @name ...`) and pass the pattern as the parameter value.

Comment: Imagine what will happen if someone enters `';DROP TABLE StudentList;--` as search criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `borrowing of books` is your table name (with whitespaces) it should be enclosed with backticks like so:

```
`borrowing of books`
```

Edit: Also, it looks like `studentnum` is missing in your where clause, so it should actually look like this:

```
sql = "select * 
   from studentlist 
   where (firstname like '%" 
 & Transaction.SEARCHSTUDENT.Text 
 & "%' or studentnum like '%" 
 & Transaction.SEARCHSTUDENT.Text 
 & "%') and studentnum not in (select studentnum from `borrowing of books` where status ='borrowed')"
```